# How can I org-store-link when ssh sudo hopping?

Tags: org-mode, tramp, ssh

I open the file like this, with hopping:

```
C-x C-f /ssh:b0ef@ximian|sudo:ximian:/etc/nixos/configuration.nix RET
```

If I call org-store link, I get this:

```
[[file:/sudo:root@ximian:/etc/nixos/configuration.nix::{ config, pkgs, ... }:]]
```

This is not correct, cause it has removed the hop and when trying to open, I get:

```
tramp-error: Host name ‘ximian’ does not match ‘\`\(?:spartacus\|\(?:127\.0\.0\.1\|::1\|localhost[46]?\)\)\'’
```

If I use scp as suggested, I get:

```
Error in post-command-hook (ivy--queue-exhibit): (user-error "Method ‘scp’ is not supported for multi-hops.")
```

Comment: Works for me: I do `C-x f  /sudo::/etc/fstab`, store the link with `C-c l`. open an Org mode file, insert the the link with `C-c C-l` and the link works. It shows `[file:/sudo:root@<hostname>:/etc/fstab]` where `<hostname>` is the FQDN of `localhost`. You need to give us more information about what you are doing exactly.

Comment: First of all, I don't understand how you do "C-x f  /sudo::/etc/fstab", cause that's opening a local file, yet your link is a network file?;)

Comment: (I meant `C-x C-f` of course, but you knew that :-) ) The link is a `file:` link: it doesn't know whether the referent is a local or a remote file. That's determined by the path. So open the file (local e.g. `/sudo:;/etc/fstab` or remote using e.g. `/scp:root@ximian:/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`, do `C-c l` in the file and then insert  the link in your Org mode file with `C-c C-l` - then test it.

Comment: BTW, the tramp `sudo` method is a local method: it just allows you to access a local file as a different user. You have to use something like the `ssh` or `scp` methods for remote access.

Comment: This command: "/scp:root@ximian:/etc/nixos/configuration.nix" would mean that the ssh server allows root logins. I'm trying to hop, first login as b0ef, then sudo on the remote system to root

Comment: That's the kind of information that you *should* have included in your question in the first place - but better late than never: thanks for adding it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions.

1. Save the hop. Set `tramp-save-ad-hoc-proxies` to `t`. With this setting, Tramp remembers that `/sudo:root@ximian:` has to use the full path `/ssh:b0ef@ximian|sudo:ximian:`.
2. Use expanded file names. In Tramp 2.6.1 (Emacs 29.2, or from GNU ELPA), set `tramp-show-ad-hoc-proxies` to `t`. By this, all hops are kept, also when you save it.

See the [Tramp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Ad_002dhoc-multi_002dhops)

N.B.: `scp` cannot be used for multi-hop file names.

Comment: Hmm, I still get the same link, even when I (setq tramp-show-ad-hoc-proxies t)

Comment: Which Emacs / Tramp version are you using?

Comment: GNU Emacs 29.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, X toolkit, cairo version 1.16.0, Xaw3d scroll bars) and Tramp 2.6.0.29.1. Ah, ok, Emacs-29.2;). That's pretty recent;) ok, grabbing it and reporting back. Hmm, I don't even have access to an Emacs-29.2 in NixOS Unstable;)

Comment: Emacs 29.2. isn't released yet, I'm building from git. Your better option is to install Tramp 2.6.1.2 from GNU ELPA. Note that there is a bug in Emacs 29.1 which prevents Tramp installation, see https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/tramp.html for mitigation action.

Comment: Thank you;) I've installed Emacs git, so the links works now;)